# What happens when await suspends an async function?

Tags: javascript, async-await

```
main(){
    PrintLotsOfStuff();
    GoShopping();
    HaveAGoodDay();

}

PrintLotsOfStuff(){
    printDailyNewsDigest();
    printWinningLotteryNumbers();
    printWeatherForecast();
    printBaseballScore();
}

async printDailyNewsDigest() {
   var newsDigest = await gatherNewsReports();
   print (newsDigest);
}

gathernewsReports() {}
```

if we look on https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/futures, we can see that gatherNewsReport() and print(newsDigest) get run after all the functions in the function that called the async function.

However, in the situation I outlined above, there is one more level. In that case, how does the flow look?

First `PrintLotsOfStuff()` calls `printDailyNewsDigest()`, which calls `gatherNewsReports()`, which then suspends, passing control back to `printLotsOfStuff()`.

This then runs printWinningLotteryNumbers, printWeatherForecast, and printBaseballScore. What happens next if the await still hasn't returned?

Does it return to the upper level and then run `GoShopping()` and `HaveAGoodDay()`?

Comment: How about testing it with some `console.log()`s?

Comment: You just asked [the exact same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56699312/does-code-higher-in-stack-get-run-while-waiting-for-await-to-complete-in-async-f), then deleted it. Why are you expecting a different response?

Comment: is it so hard to get a response. yes, I can build a fiddle. I will go do that then. I thought just asking would be easier, but I will do that then.  All I wanted was confirmation or disagreement as to whether my understanding is right or wrong

Comment: You're not returning anything... (oh, that's not what you were asking)

Comment: _"I thought just asking would be easier..."_ - Asking is fine but you're supposed to do some research before you ask. And in that case the easiest "research" would have been to execute the code (after modifying `gathernewsReports()` to return a `Promise` otherwise the `await` would be useless) and checking the output.

Comment: @andreas understanding and debugging asynchronous behaviour of JS is hard, you just have proven that by yourself (it doesn't matter wether you do `await Promise.resolve()` or `await undefined`)

Comment: @JonasWilms _"(it doesn't matter wether you do `await Promise.resolve()` or `await undefined`) "_ - And where exactly did I say that TO should return `Promise.resolve()` or `undefined`?

Comment: @andreas "otherwise the await would be useless"

Answer (score 2):

> First PrintLotsOfStuff() calls printDailyNewsDigest(), which calls gatherNewsReports, which then suspends, passing control back to printLotsOfStuff().

Exactly. In other words: `printDailyNewsDigest()` executes synchronously till it reaches the first `await`, then the function yields its execution and the function call evaluates to a Promise (so a Promise gets returned to the function that called it). As `PrintLotsOfStuff()` ignores that promise, execution will continue synchronously from then on.

> This then runs printWinningLotteryNumbers, printWeatherForecast, and printBaseballScore. What happens next if the await still hasn't returned?

Synchronous execution can't be interrupted. `printDailyDiggest` definetly did not continue execution yet.

> Does it return to the upper level and then run GoShopping() and HaveAGoodDay()?

Sure.

Now if that was done, the call stack is empty and the engine has time to execute the next task. Now somewhen whatever `printDailyDiggest` awaited will be done, and `printDailyDiggest` will continue its execution

Comment: Thank you. It's not that i don't want to do research. It's that i have a very similar case in front of me of people using async incorrectly all over the case causing all sorts of bugs. So much so that i question whether i am interpreting what i see correctly. I'm guessing that awaits on a higher level will not return till the first one returned.

Comment: Totally agree, I don't get why your previous question was downvoted (and all those other comments / answers getting it wrong proves that it is obviously not that easy)

Comment: And yes, if you would make `PrintLotsOfStuff()` `async` and would `await printDailyNewsDiggest()` then calling `PrintLotsOfStuff()` will return a Promise, that only resolves after `printDailyNewsDiggest` finished execution. That Promise can then be `await`ed again and so on.

Comment: Anyway i have used Async await a lot about 3 years ago but it wasn't buried multiple layers down and i never had to worry about these details much.